# How do I calculate the solution to this limit algebraically?

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

I was given a limit problem not dissimilar to this one:

Compute the limit of $\lim_{x \to -4} \frac{2x + 7}{3x^2 + 2x - 40}$

Since the numerator and the denominator have no common factors and the denominator approaches zero, the limit should approach $- \infty$, $+ \infty$, or it does not exist. For a limit like $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{2}{2 - x}$, I can take the left and right-hand limits as follows:

$\lim_{x \to 2^{-}} \frac{2}{2 - x} = \frac{2}{2 - 2^{-}} = \frac{2}{0} = \infty$

$\lim_{x \to 2^{+}} \frac{2}{2 - x} = \frac{2}{2 - 2^{+}} = \frac{2}{-0} = - \infty$

$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{2}{2 - x} \text{ does not exist}$

I attempted to do the same for this limit:

$\lim_{x \to -4^{-}} \frac{2x + 7}{3x^2 + 2x - 40} = \frac{-8}{48^{+} - (8^{+}) - 40}$

$\lim_{x \to -4^{+}} \frac{2x + 7}{3x^2 + 2x - 40} = \frac{-8}{48^{-} - (8^{-}) - 40}$

But I can't seem to go any farther. Looking at the graph of the equation tells you the limit does not exist, and I know that you can try substituting nearby values to -4 from both sides as well, but is there a way to compute this limit algebraically?

Comment: Are you taking limit as $x \to -3$ or $x \to -4$?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the plus represents approaching from the right and the minus represents approaching from the left.

Comment: Check that the denominator is positive for $x <-4$ and negative for $x >-4$. So the limit does not exist.

Comment: @coffeemath Sorry, that was a typo

Comment: The derivative of the denominator doesn't vanish at $x=-4$, so the denominator changes sign there, while the numerator doesn't. Thus, the fraction changes sign, so the left & right limits aren't equal, and the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @vim_overlord Yes, thought it was $x \to -3$ but now looks like it is $x \to -4.$ I now agree with geetha290 and Gerry's comments and erased my previous comment.

Comment: Why don't you decompose the denominator into the product of factors ? Then it is easier to analyze the sign on both sides of $-4.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** I might be helpful to consider one of the expressions of the right-hand side below.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to-4}\frac{2x+7}{3x^2+2x-40}&=\lim_{x\to -4}\frac{2x+7}{(x+4)(3x-10)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to-4}\left(\frac{1}{22}\,\frac{1}{x+4}+\frac{41}{22}\,\frac{1}{3x-10}\right)
\end{align*}